# Editor suggests a tag I already used

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-tags

When I was in the middle of writing a question, I noticed something curious. I had already tagged the question [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), yet it suggested I add the tag again. See the image below:

[image: Suggests python tag which it was already tagged with]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSE: [Don't suggest tags that a question has already been tagged with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183620/289905).

Comment: I mean it's not wrong. See it as a verification that you made the right choice.